# Beautify URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am having a small issue and I need some help.
In my website I have the url:

```
mydomain.com/beta/?from=boardpoint&to=destination&dateJ=02/21/2018&dateR=03/21/2018
```

where `02/21/2018` and `03/21/2018` are the `departure date` and the `arrival date`.

I want my URL to be: `mydomain.com/beta/boardpoint/destination` .

I've written in my **`.htaccess`** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)/$  /beta/?
from=$1&to=$2&dateJ=$3&dateR=$4 [L]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the leading slash from your Rewrite pattern.  Change  `^/(.*)/....` to `(.*)/....`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on condition. if your URL has 1 param then it satisfies the first condition. As well if your URL has 2 params then it will satisfy the second condition.

Hope this helps you

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ beta?p=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ beta?p=$1&sp=$2 [L]
```

Try this